# Derive Netmask given start and end IP addresses

Tags: javascript, netmask

I need to calculate the netmask given a Start and End ip address for a block in a subnet, in javascript.  I leveraged this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8872819/664479 and

With a startAddress of `ac164980` and endAddress of `ac16498e`

```
var scope = ipScope;
var s = parseInt("0x"+startAddress ,16);
var e = parseInt("0x"+endAddress ,16);
var m = parseInt("0xFFFFFFFF",16);

var nm = ""+(m ^ s ^ e);
```

I expected `FFFFFFC0` but got -15

Where'd I go wrong?

Comment: For a start you didn't convert your integers back to hexadecimal at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 2 problems here.  The first is the calculation assumption using startIP and endIP.

It really should be the `scopeSize` of the subnet that the startIP and endIP lie within.

The second is the representation of the negative value that's returned.  That's Fixed with:

```
var nm = (0xFFFFFFFF + (-1 ^(scope-1)) +1).toString(16).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the result back to hexadecimal string at the end (decimalToHexString function taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/697841/932282):

```
function decimalToHexString(number)
{
    if (number < 0)
    {
        number = 0x100000000 + number;
    }
    return number.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}

var startAddress = "ac164980",
    endAddress = "ac16498e";

var s = parseInt("0x"+startAddress, 16);
var e = parseInt("0x"+endAddress, 16);
var m = parseInt("0xFFFFFFFF", 16);

var nm = decimalToHexString(m ^ s ^ e);
```

The result is `FFFFFFF1` however.